# Android MTP USB 3.0 connection repeating errors

Tags: usb, 14.10, android, mtp

I have a laptop with USB3 port. It was pre-installed with Windows 8 and I had a weird problem when I plugged my Android phone to USB port. The USB mass storage would show up and then immediately closes and it would keep doing that until I unplug the phone. It was like as if I plug in and unplug the cable repeatedly.

I solved the problem by uninstalling the phone driver in Device Manager and re-installing it via Windows update. But now I have the same problem in Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Ubuntu Mate. As soon as I connect the phone, it sometimes mounts the memory and mostly shows random error like:

```
 - Couldn't found matching udev device.
 - Could not find "mtp://[usb:002,015]/"
 - Unable to open MTP device "[usb:002,105]"
 - No such interface 'org.gtk.vfs.Mount' on object at path/org/gtk/vfs/mount/1
```

It keeps throwing errors and won't allow me to do anything until I unplug the cable.

I have already installed `mtpfs` and `mtp-tools` and I have also created 51-android-rules based on https://github.com/snowdream/51-android.

What is the problem? Does USB3 have anything to do with this repeating errors?

**Update:**

I removed `mtpfs` and `mtp-tools` and plug the phone to a USB 2.0 port and it works better now. Still some periodic disconnects though. So it's obvious that USB 3.0 has something to do with this. Any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a bad cable. I have no idea why cuz the cable works perfectly on other machines but I just replaced the cable with another one and it seems very stable now.